# How to parse XML with cxml and stp containing ampersand

Tags: common-lisp, stp

I want to parse the following XML-Code:

```
(cxml:parse "<BEGIN><URL>www.some.de/url?some=data&bad=stuff</URL></BEGIN>" (stp:make-builder))
```

this results in

```
 #<CXML:WELL-FORMEDNESS-VIOLATION "~A" {1003C5E163}>
```

as '&' is a XML special character. But if I use `&amp;?` instead the result is:

```
(cxml:parse "<BEGIN><URL>www.some.de/url?some=data&amp;bad=stuff</URL></BEGIN>" (stp:make-builder))
=>#.(CXML-STP-IMPL::DOCUMENT
   :CHILDREN '(#.(CXML-STP:ELEMENT
                  #| :PARENT of type DOCUMENT |#
                  :CHILDREN '(#.(CXML-STP:ELEMENT
                                 #| :PARENT of type ELEMENT |#
                                 :CHILDREN '(#.(CXML-STP:TEXT
                                                #| :PARENT of type ELEMENT |#
                                                :DATA "www.some.de/url?some=data")
                                             #.(CXML-STP:TEXT
                                                #| :PARENT of type ELEMENT |#
                                                :DATA "&")
                                             #.(CXML-STP:TEXT
                                                #| :PARENT of type ELEMENT |#
                                                :DATA "bad=stuff"))
                                 :LOCAL-NAME "URL"))
                  :LOCAL-NAME "BEGIN")))
```

Which is not exactly what I expected as there should only be one CXML-STP:TEXT child with DATA "www.some.de/url?some=data&bad=stuff"

How can I fix this wrong(?) behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior, although, not very convenient, is, actually, present in many other XML parsers as well. Probably the reason for it is to be able to parse arbitrary ​XML entities and apply some user-defined rules to them. Although, it may be just a by-product of the parser implementation. I couldn't find out yet.

For the SAX variant of the parser I came to the following approach:

```
(defclass my-sax (sax:sax-parser-mixin)
  ((title :accessor title :initform nil)
   (tag :accessor tag :initform nil)
   (text :accessor text :initform "")))

(defmethod sax:start-element ((sax my-sax) namespace-uri local-name
                              qname attributes)
  (with-slots (tag tagcount text) sax
              (setf tag local-name
                    text "")))

(defmethod sax:characters ((sax my-sax) data)
  (with-slots (title tag text) sax
    (switch (tag :test 'string=)
      ("text"  (setf text (conatenate 'string text data)))
      ("title" (setf title data)))))

(defmethod sax:end-element ((sax my-sax) namespace-uri local-name qname)
  (with-slots (title tag text) sax
    (when (string= "text" local-name)
      ;; process (text sax)
    )))
```

I.e. I collect the text in `sax:characters` and process it in `sax:end-element`. In STP you, probably, can get away even easier by just concatenating neighboring `text` elements.